# Adiabatic theorem for stochastic time-dependence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differentiation, adiabatic, stochastic-processes

I am trying to derive the adiabatic theorem when my time-dependent Hamiltonian is stochastic and I have a few questions. Usually, one starts with the Schrödinger equation
\begin{equation}
i\frac{d |\psi(t)\rangle}{dt}=H_{\rm eff}(t) |\psi(t)\rangle
\end{equation}

My problem is two-fold: On one side, my Hamiltonian is non-Hermitian. On the other side, it is stochastic.

This has been my approach so far:

$\textbf{I)}$ Basis: because my Hamiltonian is non-Hermitian, if I were to diagonalize it I would need a bi-orthogonal basis. I do not want to use it, so I stick with a non-diagonal basis, such that
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle= \sum_n c_{n}(t) |\phi_n(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
such that $\langle \phi_m(t)|\phi_n(t)\rangle=\delta_{n,m}$.

$\textbf{II)}$ Adiabatic theorem:

The usual steps are the following: First, use the previously defined basis as an ansatz to the Schrödinger equations and derive the equations of motion for the coefficients $c_n(t)$.

This leads to me
\begin{equation}
i\frac{d|\psi\rangle}{dt}=i\sum_n \dot{c}_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+i\sum_n c_n(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle
\end{equation}

Which arises a fundamental question. The time dependence I have, which comes from the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ is stochastic. Then, when I use the Schrödinger equation here, can I use the usual chain rule (Stratonovich interpretation of the noise), or do I need to use Itô's lemma (Itô interpretation of the noise), where I would need to add an extra term like $\dot{c}_n|\dot{\psi}_n\rangle$?

While the usual chain rule would be preferable, I would like to stick with Itô's interpretation, because then the noise and the process are not correlated, which simplifies some expectation values.

But for now, I assume that I can use the usual chain rule. Finally, I arrive at an equation of the coefficients
\begin{equation}
i \dot{c}_m(t)=-i \sum_n c_n(t) \langle\psi_m(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle+\sum_n c_n(t) \langle\psi_m(t)|H_{\rm eff}|\psi_n(t)\rangle
\end{equation}

where the most-right element is just the matrix elements on my Hamiltonian in the basis I define, and the other term is just the overlap of my state with the other orthogonal states, which in this case is a stochastic variable. Then, solving this is equivalent to solving a stochastic differential equation.

Still, I am worried some of my argument to derive it has been wrong (mostly the chain rule).